# Show percentage values within pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have this data and created a pivot table from it. How can I get the pivot table to show data like table number 3, or even change those values to show as percentages?

[image]

Comment: @pnuts has it right. For more info [see this](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot02.html) and other Contextures pages.

Comment: This link may help : http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/how-create-pivot-table-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filename    light   distanceKM
file1       day     10
file1       day     20
file1       night   30
file1       night   5
file1       noon    10
file1       noon    10
file1       noon    10
file2       day     7
file2       night   4
```

[image]

Comment: @pnuts, good idea. To reorder click on D4 cell, and drag current pivot table D column between B and C.